# How Do I Install Packages for LyX?

Tags: software-installation, lyx

I want to install LyX for some screenplay writing and I want it to be fully functional. In the "software" there is a description of packages you can download, so I was just wondering how to install them...?

Comment: Are you talking of addons to lynx?

Comment: no. "LyX" is a document processor on Xubuntu that is supposed to be able to replace "Trelby" (screenplay writing software).

Answer (score 0):

In the Lyx "File" menu choose "New from Template" and scroll down to the Hollywood template.
Click and Enter. This is one possibility. 
To get more options you could install texlive-extras from Synaptic. Then you will need to go to the Lyx menu and click Tools>Reconfigure.
Otherwise consider specialized play writing apps like Trelby.
All the best.